# (Material-table)Unable to fetch my option list to lookup field of the table column

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui

Currently, I have a `useEffect` code like this, trying to obtain my preset options from axios get request and send it to the lookup field of the table column

```
  const [optionList, setOptionList] = useState({});


  const [columns, setColumns] = useState({
    columns: [
      {
        title: 'Image_ID',
        field: 'image_ID',
        lookup: optionList,
      },
    ]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getOption = async () => {
      let data = [];
      let options = {};
      const response = await axios.get(sampleUrl);
      const { data: { image_sample } } = response;
      image_sample.map((item) => {
        data.push(item.image_ID);
      });
      data.forEach(item => options[item] = item);
      setOptionList(JSON.stringify(options));
    }
    getOption();
  }, [])
```

Everything went well in the console, my `optionList` look exactly what I wanted:
`{"p01":"p01","p02":"p02","p03":"p03"}` However, the table options remained empty. But if you directly fetch the optionList manually to the column like this:

```
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState({
    columns: [
      {
        title: 'Image_ID',
        field: 'image_ID',
        lookup: {"p01":"p01","p02":"p02","p03":"p03"},
      },
    ]
  });
```

It will work for some reason. At some point, I suspect the `optionList` has already been sent to the table before my `useEffect` was mounted. Anyone has an idea what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because initialize of `columns.columns[0].lookup` state have set by value of `optionList`. In the first render, this state recieve a `{}` until useEffect call, inside `useEffect` setOptionList was called to change optionList state, `optionList` had change but column state not change cause this component not re-render to show what you want to see.

If you want fix it, just add `useEffect` with dependencies includes optionList and have function `setColumns`:

```
const [optionList, setOptionList] = useState({});


  const [columns, setColumns] = useState({
    columns: [
      {
        title: 'Image_ID',
        field: 'image_ID',
        lookup: optionList,
      },
    ]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getOption = async () => {
      let data = [];
      let options = {};
      const response = await axios.get(sampleUrl);
      const { data: { image_sample } } = response;
      image_sample.map((item) => {
        data.push(item.image_ID);
      });
      data.forEach(item => options[item] = item);
      setOptionList(JSON.stringify(options));
    }
    getOption();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {  // <== Add this useEffect
    setColumns({
     columns: [
      {
       title: 'Image_ID',
       field: 'image_ID',
       lookup: optionList,
      },
     ]
   }) 
  }, [optionList])
```

Comment: I also had to remove the JSON.stringify() for making it to work. Very nice answer, thank you.